# How to check if WooCommerce plugin is enabled?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to check if WooCommerce plugin is active then add some options to the option panel. but this code doesn't work right.

can anyone tell me what is wrong?

```
 if( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' )) {//add options}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
    // Yes, WooCommerce is enabled
} else {
    // WooCommerce is NOT enabled!
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot it works. and could you please tell me why that code doesn't work? all developers I see use that and works truly.

Comment: It depends of the context and where you are using the code… Also take care when you say *"All developers…"* as most of them are not really developers…

Comment: This answer is really great because it works all the time, while the class exists way only works if Woocommerce is already loaded.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, the function `is_plugin_active` method can be used to check if a plugin is active.

```
if ( is_plugin_active( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php' ) ) {
    // woocommerce is active
} else {
    // woocommerce is not active
}
```

Another method [documented in WooCommerce](https://woocommerce.com/document/query-whether-woocommerce-is-activated/) is the below option.

```
/**
 * Check if WooCommerce is activated
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'is_woocommerce_activated' ) ) {
    function is_woocommerce_activated() {
        if ( class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) ) { return true; } else { return false; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The official recommendation is to add an action handler for `woocommerce_loaded` where to perform the initialization:

> There are a few methods to achieve this. The first is to execute your code on the woocommerce_loaded action. This approach guarantees that WooCommerce and its functionalities are fully loaded and available for use. This is fired around the same time as the core plugins_loaded action.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_loaded', 'prefix_woocommerce_loaded' );

function prefix_woocommerce_loaded() {
    // Custom code here. WooCommerce is active and all plugins have been loaded...
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/docs/extension-development/check-if-woo-is-active.md